What is the name of this movie where a caveman turns out to be Jesus?
What is the name of this movie where a caveman turns out to be Jesus?
The plot goes something like this: The protagonist was moving to a new place. So, he invited his close friends for a get-together. Then he reveals that he is a caveman. Later, he reveals he is the one "Jesus". 
PS: This movie was made in a single house.

It's The man from earth. Just googled it (caveman + jesus).

Can you specify which points match the OP's criteria?

@Mooz aside from op answering it himself?
